# How can I avoid those empty strings caused by preceding or trailing whitespaces?

Tags: python, regex, split

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'[ "]+', '  a n" "c ')
['', 'a', 'n', 'c', '']
```

When there is preceding or trailing whitespace, there will be empty strings after splitting. 
How can I avoid those empty strings? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The empty values are the things between the splits. [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) is not the right tool for the job.

I recommend matching what you want instead.

```
>>> re.findall(r'[^ "]+', '  a n" "c ')
['a', 'n', 'c']
```

If you must use split, you could use a list comprehension and filter it directly.

```
>>> [x for x in re.split(r'[ "]+', '  a n" "c ') if x != '']
['a', 'n', 'c']
```

Answer (score 3):

That's what `re.split` is supposed to do. You're asking it to split the string on any runs of whitespace or quotes; if it didn't return an empty string at the start, you wouldn't be able to distinguish that case from the case with no preceding whitespace.

If what you're actually asking for is to find all runs of non-whitespace-or-quote characters, just write that:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[^ "]+', '  a n" "c ')
['a', 'n', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

I like abarnert solution.

However, you can also do (maybe not a pythonic way):

```
myString.strip()
```

Before your `split` (or etc).